# Area between the curves $y^2=x+4$ and $y^2=x$.

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate the area between the curves $y^2=x+4$ and $y^2=x$.

My teacher found the intersection points with axis $y$, $0=y^2-4$ and he obtained $y=-2$, $y=2$.
Then he formulated the integral, $$\int_{-2}^{2}[(y^2-4)-(y^2)]dy.$$
I don't understand, is this correct??

Comment: What part "I don't understand"?

Answer (score 3):

I think that part of the “solution” belongs in the problem.  The region bounded by $y^2=x+4$ and $y^2=x$ is actually infinite.  The two curves are parallel.  If that really is the question, the answer can only be $\infty$.

[image]

Another issue I would have with the solution: the integral written above, ostensibly computing an area, evaluates to $-16$.

Instead, I suspect that the task is to find the area of the region bounded by $y^2=x+4$, $y^2=x$, **and** $y=-2$ and $y=2$.  This is now a bounded region (call it $D$), and can be represented as
$$
     D = \left\{(x,y) : -2 \leq y \leq 2,\ y^2-4 \leq x \leq y^2 \right\}
$$
[image]
Therefore the area of $D$ is
$$
   A = \int_{-2}^{2} (y^2 - (y^2-4))\,dy = \int_{-2}^2 4\,dy = 16
$$

Comment: yes, but the task is find the area between the curves,  my teacher never mentioned the region bouned

Comment: @mathnew2 If so your teacher forgot part of the directions. The graphs never intersect and the area between them is infinite.

Answer (score 2):

If they intersect then $x+4=x$.